# Как производить коррекцию при умножении чисел в дополнительном коде на асм?

Tags: java, математика

Умножение целых чисел со знаком в дополнительном  коде с  неподвижной суммой частичных произведений,  сдвигом множимого влево и анализом множителя,  начиная с младших разрядов.

алгоритм на ЯВУ такой:

```
int mul(int a, int b)
{
  int res = 0;
  while(a!=0)
  {
    if((a&1)!=0)
      res += b;
    a>>=1;
    b<<=1;
  }
  return res;
}
```

А вот в каком месте корректировать полученное число, если a<0? И каким образом?

Answer (score 1):

```
int coolmul(int a, int b){
   a < 0 ? return -mul(-a, b) : return mul(a, b);
}
```

Comment: корректировка - это изменение конечного результата имеется ввиду. Т.е. если последний бит в а равен 1 надо что-то сделать чтобы ответ был верным.

Comment: Тогда в чём собственно проблема: <br /><br />

    if (a & 1 == 1) //младший бит = 1